# Booting windows after installing linux

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I have a Lenovo ideapad S510p. First I installed Windows 8 on it. Then Ubuntu 14.04. But after installing Ubuntu, I can't boot windows 8. I installed GRUB2 but I don't know how to configure it. What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: There is no UEFI firmware settings when I boot my laptop with Windows 8 DVD.

Comment: @Credo You should see firmware settings if you power on with no OS, or before OS loads (unless I'm missing something about how UEFI does things).